# Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved

Tags: eclipse, maven, selenium, proxy

I have maven project in Eclipse for seleniumm tests. I try to build tests, but get build error:

```
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connection timed out to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.5/maven-resources-plugin-2.5.pom -> [Help 1]
```

I start build by right click on pom file and chose Run as - Maven test
My pom file look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.tests</groupId>
<artifactId>ui-tests</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>tests</id>
        <properties>
            <browser.name>ie</browser.name>
        </properties>

        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>

            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.10</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.33.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.33.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
        <version>2.33.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I searched for solution and find out that I need to set proxy for maven, so I add following to settings.xml:

```
<proxies>
 <proxy>
 <id>optional</id>
   <active>true</active>
   <protocol>http</protocol>
   <host>10.192.168.87</host>
   <port>8080</port>
 </proxy>
```

Also I find out that problem could be fixed by downloading missed resources manually. I download org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin and find out where wasn't .m2 directory. I check maven version, it worked, so I create such directory manualy and set path to it in settings.xml. After this I put downloaded plugin to .m2.
But error doesn't dissapear. Could someone advise me how to fix this?

Comment: Proxy / Network configuration is wrong based on `connection timed out to...`.

Comment: Is it possible to set in sclipse use local plugins (from .m2)?

Comment: First and best is to try your build from command line and it should work without any problem. Afterwards use it in ecipse. What do you mean by `local plugins`?